# Let $T: P_2 \rightarrow P_2$ be the map $f(x) \mapsto xf'(x)$. Find the matrix $[T_B]$ associated to the basis $B = \{1, x, x^2\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I'm confused because $f(x^2) \mapsto x^2(2x) = 2x^3$, which is not in $P_2$ and I'm not sure how to represent it in the associated matrix. Did I do the calculation incorrectly?

Comment: The polynomial $f(x) = x^2 \in P_2$ is mapped to $xf'(x) = x(2x) = 2x^2 \in P_2$, that is, $T(x^2) = 2x^2$.

Comment: I think you wanted $T(x^2)= x \cdot 2x= 2x^2$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f\in P_2$ is non-constant, then $\text{deg }T\left(f\right) = \text{deg }f$. If $f\in P_2$ is a constant, then $T(f) = 0$. In particular, $T:P_2\to P_2$ is indeed a well-defined map. (The reason this is true is because the degree of $f'$ is one less than the degree of $f$ and the degree of $xf'$ is one more than the degree of $f'$, so long as $f$ is non-constant.)

We have to determine the polynomials $T(1)$, $T(x)$, and $T(x^2)$. The (three) coefficients of the polynomial $T(x^i)$ will constitute the three entries in the $(i+1)$st column of $[T_{\cal B}]$.

Hope this helps!